# DXL:Cannot assign to an attribute some properties found in history

Tags: ibm-doors

DXL, ibm DOORS
Looping through module, then through every object history, I am trying to assign to "_Owner" attribute the author from obj history who modified last time "_ReqStatus" attribute, if "_Owner" is empty.

This is what I tried:

```
Module m = current
History h
HistoryType ht 
Object o
string attributName
string authorName
string newOwner


noError()
for o in entire m do {
for h in o do
{   
    string owner = ""
    attributName=""
    attributName = h.attrName
    authorName=""
    owner = o."_Owner"

    if isDeleted(o) then continue 
    
    
    if((attributName=="_ReqStatus"))
    {   
        authorName=h.author
        //print authorName
        //print "\n"
        if(null owner)
        {   
            print identifier(o)
            print "\n"
            newOwner = authorName
            print newOwner"\n"
            owner = newOwner    
            print owner
            break       
        }
        
    }
    
}
}
ErrMess = lastError()
```

The output for `print owner` is as expected. My problem is that in-DOORS attribute is not filling at all with any value.

`_Owner` attribute type is Ennumeration and attribute properties look like this, but I don't know if it matters:
["_Owner" attr properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9JoQ.png)

Comment: Just a hint, since you are a new user here: if you feel that your question is answered, it would be good if you accept the answer, so that other users may get information from it.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `string owner = o."_Owner"`, the variable `owner` is not a handle to the object attribute itself, but the **content** of `o`'s `"_Owner"` attribute is **copied** to `owner`. So, in your later recalculation `owner = newOwner`, you only change that variable and not the attribute. Try `o."_Owner" = newOwner` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried that, but the result is the same. The "_Owner" attribute remains empty.

Comment: Found the solution: Attribute type should be `String` instead `Enumeration`. This worked for me

Comment: Well, you can use `Enumeration` just like a `String` attribute, but you need to make sure that `_Responsible_T` allows that value: https://i.imgur.com/4aQlJya.png